# Gekko - Chemical Library - How do I get the list of available component?

Tags: python, gekko

I did some test with the chemical library in Gekko. I wanted to see if I can use it with some component i'm working on right now. The test is just to try to get molecular weight for now.

Here what I tried :

```
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
c = chemical.Properties(m)
# add compounds
c.compound('water')
c.compound('Na2SO4')
# m.open_folder()
# molecular weight
mw = c.thermo('mw')
m.solve(disp=False)
print(mw)
```

Here what I did get :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 10
      7 # m.open_folder()
      8 # molecular weight
      9 mw = c.thermo('mw')
---> 10 m.solve(disp=False)
     11 print(mw)

File c:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py:2185, in GEKKO.solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2183 #print APM error message and die
   2184 if (debug >= 1) and ('@error' in response):
-> 2185     raise Exception(response)
   2187 #load results
   2188 def byte2str(byte):

Exception:  @error: Compound Not Found
 Chemical compound not found: na2so4
 All         111  available compounds are now listed in compounds.txt
 STOPPING...
```

I understand that there is no Sodium Sulfate in the database but I am supposed to be able to consult the compounds.txt file to see what are the component available. I can not find it anywhere.

Do you have an idea to where I can get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 111 compounds in the public version of Gekko. Retrieve the list with the following when there is an error and `remote=False` so that the local run directory contains the `compounds.txt` file:

```
# display 'compounds.txt'
import os
fid = open(m.path+'/compounds.txt')
print(fid.read())
fid.close()
```

Here is some of the list:

```
 Any of the following compounds can be referenced by common
   or IUPAC name, CAS number, or chemical formula
 
 Care should be taken when accessing a compound by formula
   because formula names are not unique and the first
   available match will be selected.
 
 Common Name: methane
 IUPAC Name : methane
 CAS Number : 74-82-8
 Formula    : CH4
 
 Common Name: ethane
 IUPAC Name : ethane
 CAS Number : 74-84-0
 Formula    : C2H6
...
 Common Name: dimethylaluminum chloride
 IUPAC Name : dimethylaluminum chloride
 CAS Number : 1184-58-3
 Formula    : C2H6AlCl
 
 Common Name: n-tetracontane
 IUPAC Name : n-tetracontane
 CAS Number : 4181-95-7
 Formula    : C40H82
 
 Common Name: n-pentacontane
 IUPAC Name : n-pentacontane
 CAS Number : 6596-40-3
 Formula    : C50H102
```

Here is the complete script to generate the list of compounds:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
c = chemical.Properties(m)
# add compounds
c.compound('water')
c.compound('Na2SO4')
# m.open_folder()
# molecular weight
mw = c.thermo('mw')
try:
    m.solve(disp=False)
except:
    # display 'compounds.txt'
    import os
    fid = open(m.path+'/compounds.txt')
    print(fid.read())
    fid.close()
print(mw)
```

There are 1600 compounds in the database, but the full database is not publicly available. There are freely available thermodynamic databases such as [thermo](https://pypi.org/project/thermo/), [PYroMat](http://pyromat.org/), [thermochem](https://pypi.org/project/thermochem/), [Cantera](https://cantera.org/documentation/dev/sphinx/html/cython/thermo.html), and [coolprop](https://www.coolprop.org/).

We are working on [predictive methods with machine learning](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.3c00195) so that a SMILES structure can be used to estimate some thermodynamic properties. We've made progress on normal boiling point and viscosity so far.

> Babaei, M.R., Stone, R., Knotts, T.A., Hedengren, J.D., Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation, American Chemical Society, 2023, DOI: 10.1021/acs.jctc.3c00195.